# Interceptor: actionInvocation.invoke() without return, but it also jump to the view

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-interceptors

I use struts2 to build a login platform. I use an Interceptor extends MethodFilterInterceptor. In the method doIntercept, I use "actionInvocation.invoke()" instead of "return actionInvocation.invoke()". But it also run.

struts-2.5.18

```
public class loginInterceptor extends MethodFilterInterceptor {
    @Override
    protected String doIntercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
        if (ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession().getAttribute("user") != null){
            actionInvocation.invoke();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I think because the method return null, it should not jump to the view. However, it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the ["Writing Interceptors" docs](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/writing-interceptors.html).

The important part:

> [...] `invoke` will return **after** the result has been called (eg. after your JSP has been rendered), making it perfect for things like open-session-in-view patterns. If you want to do something before the result gets called, you should implement a PreResultListener.

I.e., if you call `invoke`, the interceptors and action will be executed as normal.

To short-circuit normal processing do *not* call `invoke`, instead return a result suitable to your purposes, e.g., a login page's global result.

Comment: Thank you very much. And I am puzzled by the struts-default.xml file.Some Interceptors use : "String result = invocation.invoke(); return result;". So why still need to return result?

Comment: Struts does not know what view to serve if you do not return a result.  In this case, you would need to setup a global result for your login page.  https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/result-configuration.html see global results in the doc

Comment: Thanks. And I am not sure if my question is very naive.
Whether we want to, we can return null after the invoke method is executed? And it also jump to the view. Just like in the title.